# Saving multiple TextViews in a tableView format

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

Simple app but it's kicking my backside!  I have a tableView with 4 notes, when user clicks on one, detailView Screen pops up allowing users to enter text.  The challenge is to save each text that the user enters.  I used UserDefaults as you'll see but I am not quite getting it right.  I want to save each individual note.  However, what keeps happening is that anytime I click on the row, and enter text, and save, that text gets saved into all 4 notes.  I think my issue is coming from the didSelectRowAt() method but I am not sure.  Please take a look and tell me what I need to do to access each individual note's textView in order to save them individually.  My notes are contained in an array called notes, inside the main ViewController.swift.

here's my ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UITableViewController {
 var notes = ["Note1", "Note2", "Note3", "Note4"]
 override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

 }
 
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     return notes.count
 }
 
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
   
     cell.textLabel?.text = notes[indexPath.row]
     return cell
 }
 
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
     if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Detail") as? DetailViewController{
         vc.selectedNote = notes[indexPath.row]
         
       navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
     }
     
 }
 

 

 
     
 }
```

and here's my detailViewController

```
import UIKit

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var textView: UITextView!
    var selectedNote: String?
    var notesTwo = [String]()
    

    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let otherVC = ViewController()
     
     
            
            notesTwo = otherVC.notes
            let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
            if let noteText = defaults.string(forKey: "noteText"){

                textView.text = noteText
            }
        
        textView.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Bold", size: 18)
        
        
    }
    
 
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
      
            
            
        if let noteText = textView.text{
                let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
                defaults.set(noteText, forKey: "noteText")
            }
    }
    
   
}
```

Comment: are you using same "noteText" key to save those text view text value into a user defaults?

Comment: Yes.  How would I save each note on its own?